# Call function from one build to another

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

In my main page.dart, I have this code. When there is a text, I would like to call filter function which is declared in page B build function. How can I achieve that?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: _appBarTitle,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                                 ....
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                         // call filter function in pageB
                      },
                    );
                      ....
               }
```

Comment: Did you try - `PageB pageB = new pageB(); pageB.myFunction();`

Comment: @Sukhi yes, it said not defined.

Comment: Is it a public function ?

Comment: @Sukhi yes. I just declared them as void.

Comment: Import the dart file in pageA as "import pageb.dart". The you will be able to access function in pageB. It is not the ideal way but shall work.

Comment: @Sukhi still can't. Perhaps it can't access the method which is declared in build function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213069/discussion-between-sukhi-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do that.

As discussed on chat, `PageB().filterSearch(value)` is one way to do.

Other way is to import page b dart file and access the function. Something like :

PageA.dart :

```
import "pageb.dart"



decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                         // call filter function in pageB
                         filterSearch(value);
                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking the code below creating an `Object` of `age B` in `Page A` and calling the filter method

There are two steps needed:

> 1. Create an instance of the PageB class
> 2. Call the function ```filter() on the instance of PageB created

Check the code below, It works perfectly:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: _appBarTitle,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                                 ....
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                         // call filter function in pageB
                         //create an object of Page B
                         PageB _pageb = PageB();
                         // call the filter function in PageB using the object above
                         _pageb.filter();
                      },
                    );
                      ....
               }
```

I hope this helps you.